# mysql inner join not working correctly

Tags: mysql, join

SQL rookie here.

I'm trying to get the organisationtype name from my DB that links to a certain company.

Organisations has an ID
Organisations_organisationtypes has organisation_id and a organisationtype_id
Organisationtypes has organisationtype_id and the name of the type.

Currently I'm trying to do 2 inner joins to get there.

This step works fine:

```
select organisations.name, organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id 
from organisations
inner join organisations_organisationtypes
on         
organisations.juridicalform_id=organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id;
```

This gives me a list of COMPANY NAME - Organisationtype_id

So far so good.

Now I need to get the corresponding name for the organisationtype_id so I added following:

```
inner join organisationtypes
on organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id=organisationtypes.id
```

and changed the first line to show me the name, the complete statement is now:

```
select organisations.name, organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id, organisationtypes.name 
from organisations
inner join organisations_organisationtypes
on organisations.juridicalform_id=organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id;
inner join organisationtypes
on organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id=organisationtypes.id
```

This gives me following errors:

```
[ERROR in query 1] Unknown column 'organisationtypes.name' in 'field list'
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join organisationtypes
on organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype' at line 1
```

Comment: a comma, not a period, idk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you noticed the `;` in below line that's why the error

```
on organisations.juridicalform_id=organisations_organisationtypes.organisationtype_id;
                                                                                     ^....Here
inner join organisationtypes
```

Comment: Thank you. I am officially blind.
This returned me the correct list, with a lot of doubles.
Select distinct solved that second problem.

Comment: That should be a separate question though; BTW why not just use `DISTINCT` operator to remove the dupes.